# Is there any difference between these two sentences?

Tags: sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

1. The room that is provided with polished chairs...
2. The room provided with polished chairs...

Comment: These are not complete sentences but phrases which imply that there are further word in these sentences. These further words will affect any difference in meaning.

Comment: So , they are same in the meaning?

Comment: It all depends on context; need more context. The words "that is" can apply to either the chairs or the room...

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 As an exercise, and because I can't come up with an example, how would you finish the first sentence in such a way that _that is_ applies to the chairs?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I was thinking "The room that is provided with polished chairs by A. Smith is decorated in pale blue". ( but I see what you mean)

Comment: So, I believe the consensus is that there is no difference in meaning between the two phrases.

Answer (score 0):

'The room that is provided with polished chairs' could be a subject or a sentence as in reply to a question: Which room?

As a subject:

'The room that is provided with polished chairs is very quiet!'

vs.

'The room provided with polished chairs' is a subject since it has no verb.

Comment: Though either could be a response to a question, the first example would be an incomplete sentence which may be fine for an informal, spoken register.